# Check to see if a specific Excel file is open

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I use extensive Excel-Word linking, updated manually with VBA code. If the Excel file is not open, Word attempts to open it, warns that opening it again is trouble, requires a dialog box be answered, then go to the next link and starts again. Since there are usually 100 links, this is a big problem.

I found simple VBA code that calls a function to check if Excel is running.

```
    Dim sApp As String
    sApp = "Excel.Application"
    If IsAppRunning(sApp) = True Then
        MsgBox "Excel is Running, continue" & SourceFileName
    Else
        MsgBox "Excel is NOT Running, abort"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

I want to check if the RIGHT Excel file is open. The "right" file will have the same name as the Word file, e.g., MyDocSample.doc will be linked to MyDocSample.xls.

If MyDocSample.xls is open, then continue, if not, a warning should be posted saying "MyDocSample.xls" is not open, and offer an Abort selection.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to be in your IsAppRunning sub function. You need to identify the `.Caption` of each window within the Excel application object and compare that to your list.

```
Function IsAppRunning(ByVal sAppName) As Boolean
    Dim w As Long, oApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oApp = GetObject(, sAppName)
    If Not oApp Is Nothing Then
        For w = 1 To oApp.Windows.Count
            Debug.Print w & oApp.Windows(w).Caption
        Next w
        Set oApp = Nothing
        IsAppRunning = True
    End If
End Function
```

This rudimentary function you are using kind of depends on you only having a single *instance* (with possible multiple workbooks) of Excel open at a time. I don't believe it is going to cycle through application instances.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. That's the function that runs (other than your additions), but it doesn't solve my issue. I'm not a programmer, but here's how I think a macro would look in layman's words.

-Get the name of the Word document (without the extension)
-Look for an open Excel document with the same name (without the extension, so it could be xls, xlxs, xlsm, etc.)
-If an Excel document with the same name is open, continue to the Link  routine
-If not, warn the user and abort

Comment: @DavidEnglund a better way to control the process flow is to have your macro/procedures open the files that need to be opened... otherwise, get a handle on the Excel Application object and loop over `Workbooks` collection...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GetObject` function to return a workbook, if you know the filename.

```
Sub foo()

Dim s As String
Dim wb As Object 'Excel.Workbook

s = replace(ActiveDocument.Name, ".doc", ".xls") 'Modify if needed

Set wb = GetExcelFile(s)

If wb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "File is not open!"
    Exit Sub
End If


End Sub

Function GetExcelFile(filename As String)
Dim obj As Object 'Excel.Workbook

On Error Resume Next
Set obj = GetObject(, "Excel.Application").Workbooks(filename)
On Error GoTo 0

Set GetExcelFile = obj

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not loop through all workbooks in excel application?

```
Sub Open_Book()
    Dim varSheets As Variant
    Dim booMatch As Boolean
    Dim strFilePath As String
    strFilePath = "C:\FullFilePath"
    booMatch = False
    For Each varSheets In Application.Workbooks
        If varSheets.Name = "FileName.xls" Then
            booMatch = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next varSheets
    If booMatch = False Then
       Workbooks.Open strFilePath 
    End If
End Sub
```